# Match width of minipage footnote to table environment in which it sits

Tags: tables, footnotes, minipage, width, stata

I have placed table notes inside a `\minipage` environment, inside a `\table` environment. I want to hand the `\minipage` a width argument such that it will match any arbitrary width of the `\table` in which it sits.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
            \toprule
            & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\
            \midrule
            Outcome & 0.057 & 0.066 & 0.054 & 0.051 \\
            & (0.025) & (0.032) & (0.041) & (0.028) \\
            \bottomrule
        \end{tabular}
        \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
%       \begin{minipage}{\textwidth} -- what should go in this width argument?
            \footnotesize \textit{This is my footnote explaining the table. I would like to substitute something in for minipage's width argument such that this minipage footnote will have the same width as the table in whose environment it sits. }
        \end{minipage}
    \end{table}
Here's some text just to show how wide a paragraph is for comparison. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{document}
```

Screenshot:

[image: Screenshot of table with too-wide footnote]

I've already tried `linewidth` and `\textwidth`, with identical results. If there's a better setup for achieving my goal that doesn't involve `minipage`, I'm happy to hear it -- but it should be compatible with `tabular` if possible.

My table is produced by Stata's `esttab` command -- I don't think that should affect the answer, but I mention it in case it helps fellow Stata users who search for the same question.

Comment: see the threeparttable package (which is designed to do exactly this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of the `threeparttable` package:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{threeparttable}
\begin{document}
    \begin{table}
        \centering
        \begin{threeparttable}
            \begin{tabular}{l*{4}{c}}
                \toprule
                  & (1) & (2) & (3) & (4) \\
                \midrule
                Outcome & 0.057 & 0.066 & 0.054 & 0.051 \\
                & (0.025) & (0.032) & (0.041) & (0.028) \\
                \bottomrule
            \end{tabular}
            \begin{tablenotes}[flushleft]
                \setlength\labelsep{0pt}
                \footnotesize 
                \itshape
                \item This is my footnote explaining the table. I would like to substitute something in for minipage's width argument such that this minipage footnote will have the same width as the table in whose environment it sits. 
            \end{tablenotes}
        \end{threeparttable}
    \end{table}
Here's some text just to show how wide a paragraph is for comparison. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.
\end{document}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This solves my immediate problem, and I've accepted the answer. Thanks! I'm still curious if there happens to be an easy way to detect the width of a table or tabular environment.